# Circumvent XML double-quote escapes by using single quotes

Tags: java, xml, formatting, escaping

Is it possible to instruct a Java XML Transformer to enclose attributes in single quotes [for values containing double quotes] when possible?

```
public static void main(
    String[] pArgs
) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {
    // initialize document
    final Document doc =
     DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    final Element element = doc.createElement("a");
    element.setAttribute("b", "\"c\"");
    element.setAttribute("d", "e");
    element.setAttribute("f", "\"g'");
    element.setAttribute("h", "'i'");
    doc.appendChild(element);

    // initialize transformer
    final Transformer mTransformer =
     TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    mTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    mTransformer.setOutputProperty(
        "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2"
    );

    // write to System.out
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    final StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);
    mTransformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), streamResult);
    System.out.println(writer);
}
```

The above code outputs:

`<a b="&quot;c&quot;" d="e" f="&quot;g'" h="'i'"/>`.

I'd like for it to print:

`<a b='"c"' d="e" f="&quot;g'" h="'i'"/>`.

Actually, I don't really care how `"\"g'"` case is handled as this idiom will not occur in the documents I'm processing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing this in the XSLT language and I am not aware of any XSLT processors that support such an option.